# Can two "it" in a sentence refer to two different nouns?

Tags: american-english, pronouns

I am studying English, and I came across this example.

> "It would hardly be fair for the meatpacking industry to blame
> regulators for the harm that it has inflicted upon itself in the
> sub-prime meat sector."

I have a "Placeholder" it, which refers to "to blame...meat sector", at the beginning of the main clause; then I have another "it" in the subordinate clause ("it has inflicted upon itself in the sub-prime meat sector ").

My question is: How do I know that the second "it" refers to the industry as well as the reflexive "itself"?

It's just a matter of semantic?

Finally, is it correct saying that in a single sentence the personal pronouns should all refer to the same noun?

Comment: There's no ***syntactic*** reason why you shouldn't include multiple instances of ***it*** referring to different things in the same utterance. Here's one with three different it's -  *I considered lending him my umbrella, but  **it's** pointless giving **it** to him when **it's** not even raining.*

Comment: Here's a previous answer to a similar question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124173/using-it-multiple-times-in-a-sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "It would hardly be fair for the meatpacking industry to blame
> regulators for the harm that it has inflicted upon itself in the
> sub-prime meat sector."
>
> How do I know that the second "it" refers to the industry as well as
> the reflexive "itself"?

There is nothing else for it to refer to. "It" (singular) cannot refer to regulators (plural).